# Access UIPageViewController gesture recognizer(s) to enable swipe to delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to have swipe to delete on a `UITableView` work in conjunction with `UIPageViewController`'s paging mechanism. I want to set the `UIPageViewController`'s gesture recognizer so I can change it's delegate and implement:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if let _ = touch.view as? UITableViewCell {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

My problem is that I can't find the `UIPageViewController`'s gesture recognizer. I have tried looking in:

```
myPageViewController.gestureRecognizers
myPageViewController.view.gestureRecognizers

myPageContentViewController.gestureRecognizers
myPageContentViewController.view.gestureRecognizers
```

Where is it and/or is there a better solution to implementing a `UITableView`'s swipe to delete functionality in a `UIPageViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gestures are attached to its scrollView, and this one is not a public attribute. Anyway I use this extension to get the scrollView :

```
extension UIPageViewController {

    public var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                return scrollView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Then you want its panGesture :

```
pageController.scrollView?.panGestureRecognizer
```

Comment: I guess I should accept this answer as it answers my question as phrased, but unfortunately you are not allowed to change the delegate on the panGestureRecognizer. I get a fatal error "UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate." so my problem is still unsolved.

Comment: You can try `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;` to avoid conflicts between the swipe and the pan

Comment: @tgyhisb Interesting idea. I haven't been able to find the swipe gesture recognizer on the tableview cells AND, then I would need to call that method for every cell wouldn't I?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To handle `UITableView` cell swipes one can use [the following subclass](https://github.com/iospro/AMPageViewController) of `UIPageViewController`

It also allows to manage looping, edge bouncing, pageControl visibility.

The main idea is to add own pan gesture recogniser and override it delegate method

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

We allow or forbid simultaneous recognition for `QueuingScrollView` within `UIPageViewController` and other gestures on containing `UIScrollView`.